# remove heading in css then replace content

Tags: css, html-heading

I am writing a media query to resize a h2 element on my page. I want the old h2 content to disappear and put the new content in it's place. I have this but the display is just set to 'none' permanently:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1360px) {
h2 {
    padding-top: 0;
    display: none;
}

h2:after {
    font-size: 1em;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    content: "LoveLife. \A LoveCode"
}
}
```

Any ideas ho I can re-display it after screen re-size? Thanks

Comment: I would use the font size trick in the duplicate (ie h2 font size zero, after pseudo back to your original font size)

Comment: Please also add some HTML so this can be reproduced.